# how to propagate data down build chain using bazel aspects

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

Let's say I have a simple java program including 2 classes:

`Example`, `Example2`

and another class that uses both classes:

`ExamplesUsage`

and I have corresponding bazel build targets of kind java_library:
`example`, `example2`, `examples_usage`

so `example` and `example2` need to be compiled before examples_usage is built.

I want to accumulate information from all three targets using bazel aspects propagation technique, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for accumulating the number of source files in this build chain:

```
def _counter_aspect_impl(target, ctx):
  sources_count = len(ctx.rule.attr.srcs)
  print("%s: own amount - %s" % (target.label.name , sources_count))

  for dep in ctx.rule.attr.deps:
      sources_count = sources_count + dep.count

  print("%s: including deps: %s" % (target.label.name , sources_count))

  return struct(count = sources_count)

counter_aspect = aspect(implementation = _counter_aspect_impl,
  attr_aspects = ["deps"]
)
```

if we run it on the hypothetical java program we get the following output:

```
example2: own amount - 1.
example2: including deps: 1.
example: own amount - 1.
example: including deps: 1.
examples_usage: own amount - 1.
examples_usage: including deps: 3.
```

As you can see the 'dependencies' targets' aspects were run first, and only then the 'dependant' target aspect was run.

Of course in order to actually utilize the information some `ctx.action` or `ctx.file_action` needs to be called in order to persist the gathered data